# php mysql select order by multiple colums

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem . I want arrange order decrease of column. iphone4 ,iphone5, iphone6. For example:

```
Name |iphone4 |iphone5|iphone6 
john | 6      | 7     | 8      
Smith| 6      | 9     | 8      
Louis| 6      | 7     | 10      
Nick | 7      | 7     | 8      
john | 2      | 7     | 4 
Smith| 7      | 7     | 5
```

this is my mysql

```
Select Name, SUM(iphone4) ,SUM(iphone5),SUM(iphone6) from orders group by Name order by iphone4  DESC, iphone5 DESC, iphone6  DESC
```

but it's only working column iphone4 and iphone5. the rest, iphone6 it's don't working
Who can help me?

Comment: Is this your actual query? Why the `group by name`? Also, please edit your question to add the result you want to see, and what result the query gives...

Comment: See normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: I did update my question. Can you help me resolve my problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The order would seem to not be working if the values were stored as strings instead of numbers.

If this is the case, then converting them to numbers fixes the problem:

```
Select m.*
from mark m
order by (mathematics + 0) DESC, (physics + 0) DESC, (chemistry + 0) DESC;
```

In addition, no `GROUP BY` seems to be needed for this query.

EDIT:

For the edited version, you need the aggregations in the `order by` as well as the `select`.  To be explicit, I would write these as:

```
Select Name, SUM(iphone4+0), SUM(iphone5+0), SUM(iphone6+0)
from orders
group by Name
order by SUM(iphone4+0) desc, SUM(iphone5+0) desc, SUM(iphone6+0) desc;
```

Comment: Do not use group by any more if there is no aggregate in the select clause.  It is deprecated and seriously non-standard, so if you want to convert to another database, you will have to revise all your queries. Also, using an implicit type cast as the solution shows is not really the correct way to do this.  Look at the cast() and convert() functions.

Comment: I did update my question. Can you help me resolve my problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Cast Functions and Operators:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

> The type for the result can be one of the following values:
>
> - BINARY[(N)]
> - CHAR[(N)]
> - DATE
> - DATETIME
> - DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
> - SIGNED [INTEGER]
> - TIME
> - UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

So your query will be like that

```
Select m.*
from mark m
order by CAST(mathematics AS UNSIGNED) DESC, CAST(physics AS UNSIGNED) DESC, CAST(chemistry AS UNSIGNED) DESC;
```

Comment: I did update my question. Can you help me resolve my problem? thanks